# Can someone locate the error why the records are not displaying on the following (PHP)?

Tags: php

Can someone locate the error why the records are not displaying on the following (PHP)?

This is the code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$host="localhost";
$user="******";
$pwd="*****";
$db="my_disc_inf";

$link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pwd) or die ("Cannot Connect");
mysql_select_db($db,$link) or die ("Can't Connect To Database");

$query1="select disc_id, anime_id, fr_ep, to_ep from anime_ep_in inner join anime
        on anime_ep_in.anime_id = anime.anime_id where anime_ep_in.disc_id=".$_POST['disc_id'];
$query2="select disc_title from disc where disc_id=".$_POST['disc_id'];

$result1=mysql_query($query1);
$result2=mysql_query($query2);

mysql_close($close);
```

And in the html this is the code with PHP:

```
Contents of Disc
<?php
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
        print($row2['disc_title']);
    }
?>

<?php
    print("<tr>
        <th>Anime ID</th>
        <th>Anime Name</th>
        <th>Episodes</th>
        </tr>");
    while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
        print("<tr><td>".$row1['anime_id']."</td><td>".$row1['anime_title']."</td>");
        print("<td>".$row1['fr_ep']."-".$row1['to_ep']."</td></tr>");
    }
?>
```

I'm still new to php, but I just want to know in advance....
I've skipped typing the html codes so don't mind the html codes...

---

I think I'll just say what I really want to get... ^^
I want a result like this to be seen

```
ANIME ID | ANIME TITLE | EPISODES
1          fairy tail    1-10
2          naruto        2-20
...etc

something like that...

in mysql table anime contains 
-anime_id
-anime_title

table anime_ep_in
-anime_id (foreign key references anime.anime_id) 
-fr_ep (From Episode) 
-to_ep (To Episode)
```

that isn't the complete fields in the table though but they are the important parts to display what I want. Any Suggesions?

You might also want to use the php above and edit it so I can try it if it works...

Comment: $row1['anime_title'] this will never show, in the query you haven't selected the columns.

Comment: `mysql_close($link);` not a `mysql_close($close);`

Comment: You don't say what results or errors you're getting.

Comment: When you search for errors, why do you disable error_reporting?

Comment: mysql_close() is used wrong, like @KrishR mentioned. But also you should close after the second code example, I think. So, after you used mysql_fetch_array()...

Comment: Worth mentioning: using mysql_* is asking for problems. It was never a particularly good set of functions to begin with (left as an exercise for the reader), and it's deprecated (on its way out) now, so you run the risk that your page - assuming it's a webpage from the output - stops working when a system update grabs the version of PHP that finally removes it completely.

Comment: I've tried the changing my error_reporting(0);

Comment: OK thanks everyone... I've solved the problem...I just changed the select anime_id etc... to select * from anime etc...
Thanks for your help!!! I'm getting used on removing the error_reporting ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some things you want to do while debugging.

First of all is setting error_reporting to E_ALL as Marcel Balzer already mentioned.
With that you'll see Fatal errors which will stop the script immediatly (It will also show any error, but only fatal errors will stop the script).

Check for `mysql_error`s.

There is nothing printed? Check if the while is getting through. If it is, check the contents of `$row` (see `var_dump` and `print_r`).

`Mysql_*` is fine for learning purposes but take a look at PDO, SQL Injection and MySQLi.

Learning to debug is a simple thing that many many people don't want to do apparently. 
You can echo almost anything and you'll get to the point where a variable doesn't contain the value it should.

Comment: I'm sorry about the "error_reporting(0);" part. Its just that the time I used simple PHP codes I get a lot of errors but the result is fine that's why I added it. I remove it sometimes though whenever I search for errors and then put it back when I got what I want.

Comment: Don't put it to zero then ;-) E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE for example.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the error_reporting(0) with the following:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);
```

Comment: ok...i'll do that...thanks